# Access Existing C source file Using Java JNI

Tags: java

I have four C file. Two of them are header file.

```
1.Const.h contains
extern float Hx_g0;


2.Const.c contains
float Hx_g0=-2.89356745;


3.Calculation.h contains
void calculation();


4.Calculation.c contains
#include"calculation.h"
#include "stdio.h"
void calculation(){
printf("Calculation done");
}
```

Now how can i use method calculation() of the Calculation.c using JNI. In the net i found HelloWorld example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, modify the "hello world" example to call `calculation()` from the C method. Sorry this isn't more profound, but that's about it.

```
#include "calculation.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloWorld_print(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
    calculation();
    return;
}
```

When you build your library, make sure to include `calculation.c`.